# RecyclerView does not update after deleting filter input search

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that i filter with a search input.
the problem is that for exemple if i serch for "ber" it filters but if i change the letters or delete them the list does not update.
Can anyone help?

filter function code :

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{
    return new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence)
        {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for your list
            if(charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0)
            {
                results.values = cityList;
                results.count = cityList.size();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<City> filteredResultsData = new ArrayList<City>();

                for(City data : cityList)
                {
                    if(data.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        filteredResultsData.add(data);
                    }

                }

                results.values = filteredResultsData;
                results.count = filteredResultsData.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults)
        {
            cityList = (ArrayList<City>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

listener code:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code or we won't be able to help

Comment: i added my code

Comment: i want to clarify that the same code was working on a lstview the problem showed when i switched

Comment: i dont know how to use it, maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
         filteredList.addAll(contactsList);
    }
```

This is `onTextChanged()` , Where filteredList the searched content and contactList is the complete list, both of them are the arraylist of object as in my case was of `userdetails`

Here is the complete example in my application, This logic work in both cases i.e., deleting and changing searching characters

```
private void addSearchListener() {

        mySearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                filteredList.clear();
                charSequence = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    filteredList.addAll(contactsList);
                } else
                    for (int j = 0; j < contactsList.size(); j++) {
                        final Userdetails userdetails = contactsList.get(j);
                        String name = userdetails.getName();
                        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(contactsList.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                Collections.sort(filteredList, (u1, t1) -> u1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(t1.getName()));
                mfilteredAdapter = new ContactsRecylerviewAdapater(filteredList, ContactsList.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mfilteredAdapter);
                mfilteredAdapter.notifyAdapterDataSetChanged(ContactsList.this);
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: i want to clarify that the same code was working on a lstview the problem showed when i switched

Comment: lol, same kind of method didn't work in my case, so made my own. wait let me look at your code

Comment: Don't know why your code is not working, try debugging on your list values by debugger or with logs